# Can you show me the error for the following code?

Tags: unix, sh

I am getting the error `countprocess_flag cannot be found..` when executing the below code:

```
if [ $v2 -eq 2 ]; then    
    countprocess_flag = 1
else
    countprocess_flag = 0
fi
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the fi for at the end of your if else?

Comment: The erroneous spaces in the assignments have already been pointed out. While fixing your syntax, you should also add quotes around the `$v2` in order to avoid errors when it's unset.

Comment: @JoshMein: That's part of the syntax of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Assignment in Bourne shell must be done without spaces around the `=`

Comment: Are you getting other errors that would lead you to believe there are further mistakes?